# Git Failes to push some refs, Updates were rejected

Tags: git, github, push

I'm getting this message when I tried to push changes. How to merge my local repository and remote one? I copied project folder and did:

```
git init

git remote add Myprojectname path-to-my-project.git
git commit -a -m "msg"

git pull origin master

git push origin mybranch
```

And I'm getting this error:

`Git Failes to push some refs, Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote changes.`

How to fix that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What returns `git remote -v`?

Comment: It returns this: `myproject https://github.com/myproject.git (fetch) myproject https://github.com/myproject.git (push) origin https://github.com/myproject (fetch) origin https://github.com/myproject (push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you add that remote? `git remote add Myprojectname path-to-my-project.git`. From what I know you should rather add `git remote add origin path-to-my-project.git` when adding github project. Please remove `Myprojectname` remote using this command `git remote rm myproject` and `git remote rm origin` and add the remote like that `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`. Then you can pull and push to it. Btw you don't have to specify origin in that case, just `git push`

Comment: Thank you fo your answer! I did it and now I get this: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge. Is it ok now to git push or it isn't? The last changes are in my local repository .

Comment: I also did this before your answer: `git rebase -i origin/master` - how to undo it?

Comment: Did you try to pull first?

Comment: Yes, I got this error when I pulled. And Is there a problem because of this rebase? Now, in console, it's written `d:/xampp/htdocs/myproject (myname| Rebase -i)

Comment: `git checkout master` and after that `git pull`. If you care about your changes then copy changed files to some directory outside your repo.

Comment: I want to push to mybranch. Should I checkout branch master or checkout mybranch?

Comment: On which branch did you commit your changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92306/discussion-between-grimsock-and-ci-lover).